# ERRO Could not open connection e user root

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Está acontecendo estes erros abaixo na minha aplicação:

Obs: Estou usando Maven.

Seguem uma imagem de como está a estrutura do projeto no eclipse:

[image: Erros no eclipse]

Segue os erros abaixo:

```
out 22, 2015 11:03:58 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
out 22, 2015 11:03:58 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
out 22, 2015 11:03:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
out 22, 2015 11:03:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fabricaweb2db]
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
out 22, 2015 11:03:59 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
out 22, 2015 11:04:00 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
out 22, 2015 11:04:00 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
out 22, 2015 11:04:00 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at fabricaweb2.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:13)

out 22, 2015 11:04:00 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at fabricaweb2.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:13)

out 22, 2015 11:04:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
out 22, 2015 11:04:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
    at fabricaweb2.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 6 more
```

Segue o `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="fabricaweb2db" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
        <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <!-- dados da conexao --> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fabricaweb2db"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <!-- atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Segue o `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.fabricaprogramador</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabricaprogramador</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Dependdecias do Hibernate -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.hibernate </groupId>
            <artifactId> hibernate-validator </artifactId>
            <version> 4.3.0.Final </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Driver jdbc do postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>fabricaweb2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Segue a classe `TesteHibernate`:

```java
package fabricaweb2;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import br.com.fabricaprogramador.entidades.Usuario;

public class TestHibernate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fabrica de EntityManagerFactory
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("fabricaweb2db");
        // Gerenciador de entidades
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


        // Inicando a Transação
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
        // Cria o Objeto Usuario 
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(); 
        usuario.setNome("Pedro"); 
        usuario.setLogin("p");  
        usuario.setSenha("234"); 

        // Prepara a instrução SQL 
        em.persist(usuario);
        // Confirmando a transação, fazendo a persistencia no banco 
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

Segue a classe `Usuario`:

```
package br.com.fabricaprogramador.entidades; 

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable{ 

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id; 
    private String nome;
    private String login;
    private String senha;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    } 
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((login == null) ? 0 : login.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((senha == null) ? 0 : senha.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (login == null) {
            if (other.login != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!login.equals(other.login))
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null) 
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        if (senha == null) {
            if (other.senha != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!senha.equals(other.senha))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Você está informando a senha correta para o PostgreSQL? - `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"`

Comment: Sim, usuario e senha criei como "root" no postgree

Comment: A URL está correta? `[jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fabricaweb2db]`

Comment: Acabei de testa essa URL: ' jdbc:postgresql://localhost/fabricaweb2db"/> ' mas continua o mesmo errro

Comment: E se você mudar a versão do `hibernate-core`, do `hibernate-entitymanager` e do `hibernate-jpamodelgen` no `pom.xml` para a **5.0.2.Final** (a mais recente), o `hibernate-validator` para a **5.2.2.Final**, o `hibernate-commons-annotations` para a **3.3.0.ga**, trocar o `postgresql:postgresql` para `org.postgresql:postgresql` versão **9.4-1204-jdbc42** e o SLF4J para a versão **1.7.12**? Noto isso em especial no hibernate aonde as versões do `hibernate-core`, do `hibernate-entitymanager` e do `hibernate-jpamodelgen` deveriam estar casadas, mas não estão no seu `pom.xml`.

Comment: Fiz o seu procedimento acima, apareceu este erro no pom.xml : ' Missing artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1204-jdbc42 '

Comment: Ja corrigir o erro acima, vou tentar rodar aq

Comment: É **org.** postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1204-jdbc42. Eles decidiram renomear o grupo deles recentemente acrescentando o prefixo "**org.**".

Comment: Apareceu este erro: Unable to build entity manager factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala José!

Cara, a exceção que está retornando pelo seu BD é clara, falha ao autenticar o usuário root, tente conectar através de um outro client ou do código do MKYONG (http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/), Bem simples, apenas para validar se é sua app ou o banco!

1. Verifique se o usuário root possui a permissão de acesso
2. Verifique se o root está desbloqueado (Pode ter sido bloqueado)
   (Caso ele esteja bloqueado, e após o desbloqueio ele volte a bloquear ao rodar a aplicação, pode ser que tenha sido ativado alguma proteção, aí só reduzir o pool e e usar um pooled datasource).
3. Ultimo caso, reinstala o BD.

Comment: Era isso mesmo , resolveu... vlw